# Github's "source code (zip)" is incomplete? (folder missing)

Tags: github, zip, repository, open-source

On Github repository I have one file ("*changelog.txt*") and one folder ("*source*") containing, as the name suggests, the source code of the zipped executable (the program). See [Github Repository](https://github.com/TheSatanRecords/The-Satan-Records-Legacy-Audio-Player).

However, when I go to the release page - see [Github Release](https://github.com/TheSatanRecords/The-Satan-Records-Legacy-Audio-Player/releases/tag/1.0.0) - I can download the zipped executable, but when I try to download the source code - see [Source Code (zip)](https://github.com/TheSatanRecords/The-Satan-Records-Legacy-Audio-Player/archive/refs/tags/1.0.0.zip) - there is only "*changelog.txt*", and the entire "*source*" folder (containing the actual code) is missing.

I understand that Github's "Source Code (zip)" is auto-generated based on the content of the repository, so I deleted the old release, and created a new one + re-uploaded the zipped executable, but it doesn't seem to work and I still have only "*changelog.txt*" when I try to download the source.

It's not the end of the world since the source code is still accessible from the repository (see the first link), but such a problem could potentially annoy the people who would like to download the source from the release page.

Is there a solution ? Or did I do something the wrong way ?

Thanks for your answers, and sorry for my bad English (it is not my native tongue).

Comment: It looks like the `src` directory is present just fine to me.  What program are you using to inspect it?  Does it support Zip64 properly?

Comment: I found a solution. I had to delete the ENTIRE "1.0.0" (version) **tag**, not just the release. I restarted everything from scratch, and it worked. Thanks for your answer @bk2204 !